# Is there an algorithm for removing a dash ("-") between two words and then contracting them?

Tags: r, text, topic-modeling, quanteda

I have a lot of text of words with dashes between new lines like so:

```
vec <- "Today is a good day because the sun is shin- ing."
```

What I want is instead:

```
"Today is a good day because the sun is shining."
```

But I don't want it just for specific words but for all words that are being "broken up" like that. It seems like something you should be able to do in Word format, but I haven't been able to figure out how, so maybe it's more complicated.

For the record, I am using `readtext`/`quanteda` package, but I can't find anything there either that can do this by default at least.

Is there some simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way. We can use `str_replace_all` from the `stringr` package.

```
vec <- "Today is a good day because the sun is shin- ing."

library(stringr)

vec2 <- str_replace_all(vec, "-\\s+", "")

vec2
# [1] "Today is a good day because the sun is shining."
```

Comment: If there is one or more space after the hyphen perhaps something like `gsub("-\\s+", "", vec)`

Comment: @user20650 Thank you. I have edited my post based on your suggestion.

Comment: thanks. perhaps `"-\\s*"` is better if there is no space (as in your vector)

Comment: @user20650 Thanks. I also updated that. For some reasons, there was no space when I first saw this question. Someone must edit the question later.

Comment: Yes, that was my slow editing. Although I think I may have messed up the OP vector; I have a feeling there should be a newline instead of a space after the hyphen. If so, It would be good if they added `dput(vec)` to their question.

Comment: @user20650 I agree. I hope OP see your suggestions on the `dput(vec)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It definitely works on words that are separated by newlines like "shin-\n ing, but somehow seems to ignore words that aren't, like "shin-ing". Do you have any idea why it does that?

Comment: @MaltheFrøkjær-Rubbås; try the regex given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67138041/is-there-an-algorithm-for-removing-a-dash-between-two-words-and-then-contr/67138109#comment118672806_67138109) e.g. `vec <- c("shin-\n ing", "shin-ing");
gsub("-\\s*", "", vec)`

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly a good solution to fix this in the character inputs before creating quanteda objects (corpus, tokens, etc.).  An alternative in quanteda is to tokenise the texts with the ending hyphens, then:

- compound the hyphenated tokens with the token that follows
- remove the new tokens with their internal hyphens

Example:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 3.0.0
## Unicode version: 10.0
## ICU version: 61.1
## Parallel computing: 12 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

txt <- c(
  "The sun is shin- ing.",
  "Hyphen- ation is fun",
  "text an- alysis"
)
toks <- tokens(txt)
toks
## Tokens consisting of 3 documents.
## text1 :
## [1] "The"   "sun"   "is"    "shin-" "ing"   "."    
## 
## text2 :
## [1] "Hyphen-" "ation"   "is"      "fun"    
## 
## text3 :
## [1] "text"   "an-"    "alysis"
```

The compounding step:

```r
toksc <- tokens_compound(toks, phrase("*- *"), concatenator = "")
toksc
## Tokens consisting of 3 documents.
## text1 :
## [1] "The"      "sun"      "is"       "shin-ing" "."       
## 
## text2 :
## [1] "Hyphen-ation" "is"           "fun"         
## 
## text3 :
## [1] "text"      "an-alysis"
```

And finally the replacement without hyphens step:

```r
toks_hyphenated <- grep("\\w+-\\w+", types(toksc), value = TRUE)
tokens_replace(toksc, toks_hyphenated, gsub("-", "", toks_hyphenated))
## Tokens consisting of 3 documents.
## text1 :
## [1] "The"     "sun"     "is"      "shining" "."      
## 
## text2 :
## [1] "Hyphenation" "is"          "fun"        
## 
## text3 :
## [1] "text"     "analysis"
```

**Edit: Added to question**

If you really want to recombine these to make a corpus from the processed tokens, you can apply this step:

```
> toks_rejoined <- tokens_replace(toksc, toks_hyphenated, gsub("-", "", 
> corpus(sapply(toks_rejoined, paste, collapse = " "))
Corpus consisting of 3 documents.
text1 :
"The sun is shining ."

text2 :
"Hyphenation is fun"

text3 :
"text analysis"
```

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer. Although a bit complicated, it definitely works! Just for curiosity's sake, is there a way to "reconstruct" the corpus object, so that it reflects the changes that have been made on the tokens-level?

Comment: See added final part of my answer.

Comment: @KenBenoit This is great. However, tokens_compound is super slow when applied to large tokens objects. Is there an alternative way, or perhaps even a neat solution in `Python` using `nltk`?

Comment: Never mind, I think I found a surprisingly simple solution, namely to remove the hyphens at the corpus stage (unit = sentences) before tokenization. Is that not much faster? See below:

Comment: `corpus(txt) %>% corpus_reshape(to = "sentences") %>% gsub(., pattern = "-\\s+", replacement = "") %>% tokens()`